# NetWorkInfo, connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo, and .IsConnected are obsolete

Tags: c#, android, connectivity

I have an app that is targeting Android 8.0 (API Level 26 - Oreo) through Android 10.0 (API Level 29 - Q) and the following code is depreciated:

```
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
            NetworkInfo activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;
            bool isOnline = (activeConnection != null) && activeConnection.IsConnected;
```

If `NetworkInfo` and anything associated with it is depreciated, what do I use in it's place.  I've researched this issue all day and EVERY suggestion I've seen uses functionality that is depreciated (and written in java which is a total mystery to me).  So please don't tell me this is a duplicated of some issue already posted somewhere, it's not.  Also, if you provide code, please c#.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo has a box with details of the `ConnectivityManager` alternatives that Google would like you to use on Android Q and higher.

Comment: Yes, saw this but I have no idea how to use it to test for a connection.

Answer (score 0):

Although the code is in Kotlin, I hope you will understand whats the alternative.

```
fun isConnectedToTheInternet(): Boolean {
        val cm = application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            cm.run {
                cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)?.run {
                    return when {
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                        else -> false
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            cm.run {
                cm.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                    if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        return true
                    } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    }
```

Comment: I gave it my best shot, but I m unable to convert this code to c#.  See my post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611166/convert-from-kotlin-to-c-sharp
Also, the use of `activeNetwork` is going to be a problem becasue `activeNetwork` is depreciated in API 29.

Comment: I am really not a c# developer. activeNetworkInfo is deprecated from Build.VERSION_CODES.M. So, it should be alright.

Comment: Of course, sorry I've gotten wrapped around the axle with this.  I'm still trying to convert this.  Looking at the other answer I've gotten on the conversion question.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help you or if someone can convert this code to C#.

This code is **functional in Kotlin** and is **not depreciated**.

```
private fun isInternetConnection(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val capability = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
    return capability?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) ?: false
}
```

Hoping to have helped you