# Convert from kotlin to c#

Tags: c#, android

I need to convert the following code from kotlin to c#.

kotlin code:

```
fun isConnectedToTheInternet(): Boolean {
        val cm = application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            cm.run {
                cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)?.run {
                    return when {
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
                        hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
                        else -> false
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            cm.run {
                cm.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                    if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        return true
                    } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false
    }
```

this is what I been able to convert thus far.  I am unable to convert that which is commented:

```
    public Boolean isConnectedToTheInternet(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.M)
        {
//            cm.run {
//                cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork)?.run {
//                    return when {
//                        hasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Wifi)-> true
//                        hasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Cellular)-> true
//                        hasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Ethernet)-> true
//                    else -> false
//                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
//            cm.run {
//                cm.ActiveNetworkInfo?.run {
//                    if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
//                    {
//                        return true;
//                    }
//                    else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
//                    {
                        return true;
                  }
                }
            }
        }
```

With c# code `ConnectivityManager` doesn't have a `.run` method or property and I am unable to find something compatible.  Not knowing ANYTHING about kotlin is a real problem for me in this conversion.  I could use some assistance.  Thanks.

*** Update ***

Thanks to @Oscar Emilio Perez Martinez, We've managed to get to this:

```
    public static Boolean IsConnectedToTheInternet(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.M)
        {
            return cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork).HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Wifi) || cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork).HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Cellular) || cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork).HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Ethernet);
        }
        else
        {
            return cm.ActiveNetworkInfo.Type == ConnectivityType.Wifi || cm.ActiveNetworkInfo.Type == ConnectivityType.Mobile;
        }
    }
```

But now I get an error on the line `ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);` that says `The name 'ConnectivityService' does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: _"Not knowing ANYTHING about kotlin is a real problem for me..."_ - then maybe you can just [google a little](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) ?

Comment: Been doing that for the last 5 hours ... but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ok, look. I don't now anything about kotlin too, but with a little googling, I found [this](https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84) and now I know, that `run` is just a way of scoping your code within kotlin. You may just leave it. So first part of code is translated to somekind of `if (cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork)?.HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Wifi) || ...) // 2 more checks` and a second one is translated to `if (cm.ActiveNetworkInfo?.Type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || ...) // 1 more check`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First import `android content` as below

```
using Android.Content;
```

Then declare connectivity manager as below

```
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);
```

and the first block of code would be translate as below.

```
return cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork).HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Wifi) || cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork).HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Cellular) || cm.GetNetworkCapabilities(cm.ActiveNetwork).HasTransport(Android.Net.TransportType.Ethernet);
```

and the second block of code would be translate as below

```
 return cm.ActiveNetworkInfo.Type  ==  ConnectivityType.Wifi ||
          cm.ActiveNetworkInfo.Type == ConnectivityType.Mobile;
```

> Run doesn't exists in xamarin because is not a part of the android
>   sdk. In fact is part of the kotlin scope functions.Take a look at the official [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) of kotlin.

PD: I code in kotlin everyday for my job and i code in c# for hobbie :)

Comment: In the second block I get the error:
`ConnectivityManager does not contain a definition for TYPE_WIFI` or `TYPE_MOBILE`.

Comment: Please, see the edited answer, I think it should work now!

Comment: Sorry, now I get the error `operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Type' and 'Connectivity.Type'`.  This has been my life the last two days.

Comment: Let me check it, I'm downloading visual studio for Mac.

Comment: I got it, check the edit answer, need to use Type instead of GetType.

Comment: Now I get an error on this line:

`            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
`, `The name 'ConnectivityService' does not exist in the current context`.  Frustrating.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. I hope it helps you and please vote my answer